Slide mechanic with Character Controller
So I need to have a functional FPS game by next tuesday, and I’ve been pretty busy working on other things. I’m a newbie in Unity, so I’ve been following tutorial for the most part. I built my character controller based on this amazing tutorial series by Comp-3 Interactive.
It works great, but I would really like to add a slide mechanic, which I assume would be pretty easy given the code for crouching. Thing is I have no idea how to do it, and I’ve used too much time trying to investigate how to do it. If anyone knows an easy way to add this function I would really appreciate it
Btw, when I say slide I don't mean slope slide, I mean run and then slide
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControllerV2 : MonoBehaviour
{

    public bool canMove { get; private set; } = true;
    private bool isSpritning => canSprint && Input.GetKey(sprintKey);
    private bool shouldJump => Input.GetKeyDown(jumpKey) && characterController.isGrounded;
    private bool shouldCrouch => Input.GetKeyDown(crouchKey) || Input.GetKeyUp(crouchKey) && !duringCrouchAnimation && characterController.isGrounded;

    [Header("Functional Options")]
    [SerializeField] private bool canSprint = true;
    [SerializeField] private bool canJump = true;
    [SerializeField] private bool canCrouch = true;
    [SerializeField] private bool canUseHeadbob = true;
    [SerializeField] private bool willSlideOnSlopes = true;
    [SerializeField] private bool canZoom = true;

    [Header("Controls")]
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode sprintKey = KeyCode.LeftShift;
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode jumpKey = KeyCode.Space;
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode crouchKey = KeyCode.C;
    // [SerializeField] private KeyCode slideKey = KeyCode.LeftControl;
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode zoomKey = KeyCode.Mouse1;

    [Header("Movement Parameters")]
    [SerializeField] private float walkSpeed = 3.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float sprintSpeed = 6.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float crouchSpeed = 1.5f;
    [SerializeField] private float slopeSpeed = 8f;
    
    [Header("Look Parameters")]
    [SerializeField, Range(1, 10)] private float lookSpeedX = 2.0f;
    [SerializeField, Range(1, 10)] private float lookSpeedY = 2.0f;
    [SerializeField, Range(1, 100)] private float upperLookLimit = 80.0f;
    [SerializeField, Range(1, 100)] private float lowerLookLimit = 80.0f;

    [Header("Jumping Parameters")]
    [SerializeField] private float jumpForce = 8.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float gravity = 30.0f;

    [Header("Crouch Parameters")]
    [SerializeField] private float crouchHeight = 0.5f;
    [SerializeField] private float standingHeight = 2f;
    [SerializeField] private float timeToCrouch = 0.25f;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 crouchingCenter = new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0);
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 standingCenter = new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0);
    public bool isCrouching;
    private bool duringCrouchAnimation;

    [Header("Headbob Parameters")]
    [SerializeField] private float walkBobSpeed = 14f;
    [SerializeField] private float walkBobAmount = 0.05f;
    [SerializeField] private float sprintBobSpeed = 18f;
    [SerializeField] private float sprintBobAmount = 0.11f;
    [SerializeField] private float crouchBobSpeed = 8f;
    [SerializeField] private float crouchBobAmount = 0.025f;
    private float defaultYPos = 0;
    private float timer;

    [Header("Zoom Parameters")]
    [SerializeField] private float timeToZoom = 0.1f;
    [SerializeField] private float zoomFOV = 54f;
    private float defaultFOV;
    private Coroutine zoomRoutine;

    // Slope sliding parameters
    private Vector3 hitPointNormal;
    private bool isSliding
    { 
        get 
        {
            if(characterController.isGrounded && Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out RaycastHit slopeHit, 2f))
            {
                hitPointNormal = slopeHit.normal;
                return Vector3.Angle(hitPointNormal, Vector3.up) > characterController.slopeLimit;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }


    private Camera playerCamera;
    public CharacterController characterController;

    private Vector3 moveDirection;
    private Vector2 currentInput;

    private float rotationX = 0;

    private void Awake() 
    {
        playerCamera = GetComponentInChildren<Camera>();
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

        defaultYPos = playerCamera.transform.position.y;

        defaultFOV = playerCamera.fieldOfView;

        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    private void Update() 
    {
        if (canMove)
        {
            HandleMovementInput();
            HandleMouseLook();

            if (canJump)
            {
                HandleJump();
            }

            if (canCrouch)
            {
                HandleCrouch();
            }

            if (canUseHeadbob)
            {
                HandleHeadbob();
            }

            if (canZoom)
            {
                HandleZoom();
            }

            ApplyFinalMovements();
        }
    }

    private void HandleMovementInput()
    {
        currentInput = new Vector2((isCrouching ? crouchSpeed : isSpritning ? sprintSpeed :  walkSpeed) * Input.GetAxis("Vertical"),
        (isCrouching ? crouchSpeed : isSpritning ? sprintSpeed :  walkSpeed) * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));

        float moveDirectionY = moveDirection.y;
        moveDirection = (transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * currentInput.x) + (transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right) * currentInput.y);
        moveDirection.y = moveDirectionY;
    }

    private void HandleMouseLook()
    {
        rotationX -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * lookSpeedY;
        rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(rotationX, -upperLookLimit, lowerLookLimit);

        playerCamera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationX, 0, 0);
        transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * lookSpeedX, 0);
        
    }

    private void HandleJump()
    {
        if(shouldJump)
        {
            moveDirection.y = jumpForce;
        }
    }

    private void HandleCrouch()
    {
        if (shouldCrouch)
        {
            StartCoroutine(CrouchStand());
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator CrouchStand()
    {
        if(isCrouching && Physics.Raycast(playerCamera.transform.position, Vector3.up, 1f))
        {
            yield break;
        }
        duringCrouchAnimation = true;

        float timeElapsed = 0;
        float targetHeight = isCrouching ? standingHeight : crouchHeight;
        float currentHeight = characterController.height;
        Vector3 targetCenter = isCrouching ? standingCenter : crouchingCenter;
        Vector3 currentCenter = characterController.center;

        isCrouching = !isCrouching;

        while (timeElapsed < timeToCrouch)
        {
            characterController.height = Mathf.Lerp(currentHeight, targetHeight, timeElapsed / timeToCrouch);
            characterController.center = Vector3.Lerp(currentCenter, targetCenter, timeElapsed / timeToCrouch);
            timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }

        characterController.height = targetHeight;
        characterController.center = targetCenter;

        duringCrouchAnimation = false;
    }
    
    private void HandleHeadbob()
    {
        if (!characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            return;
        }

        if(Mathf.Abs(moveDirection.x) > 0.1f || Mathf.Abs(moveDirection.z) > 0.1f)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime * (isCrouching ? crouchBobSpeed : isSpritning ? sprintBobSpeed : walkBobSpeed);
            playerCamera.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(
                playerCamera.transform.localPosition.x,
                defaultYPos + Mathf.Sin(timer) * (isCrouching ? crouchBobAmount : isSpritning ? sprintBobAmount : walkBobAmount),
                playerCamera.transform.localPosition.z);
        }
    }

    private void HandleZoom()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(zoomKey))
        {
            if(zoomRoutine != null)
            {
                StopCoroutine(zoomRoutine);
                zoomRoutine = null;
            }

            zoomRoutine = StartCoroutine(ToggleZoom(true));
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyUp(zoomKey))
        {
            if(zoomRoutine != null)
            {
                StopCoroutine(zoomRoutine);
                zoomRoutine = null;
            }

            zoomRoutine = StartCoroutine(ToggleZoom(false));
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator ToggleZoom(bool isEnter)
    {
        float targetFOV = isEnter ? zoomFOV : defaultFOV;
        float startingFOV = playerCamera.fieldOfView;
        float timeElapsed = 0;

        while(timeElapsed < timeToZoom)
        {
            playerCamera.fieldOfView = Mathf.LerpAngle(startingFOV, targetFOV, timeElapsed / timeToZoom);
            timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }

        playerCamera.fieldOfView = targetFOV;
        zoomRoutine = null;
    }

    private void ApplyFinalMovements()
    {
        if (!characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (willSlideOnSlopes && isSliding)
        {
            moveDirection += new Vector3(hitPointNormal.x, -hitPointNormal.y, hitPointNormal.z) * slopeSpeed;
        }

        characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}

I tried to follow some tutorials on sliding, but most of them are about slope sliding, which I already implemented. I also wouldn't really like to use a Rigidbody since I'm pretty comfortable with the Character Controller component

Just in case anyone is interested, I figured it out! I'm pretty sure it's not optimal, but for the time constraint I have it works. Here's what I did:
I created some variables
[Header("Sliding Parameters")]
    [SerializeField] private float slideSpeed = 8.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float slideDuration = 1.0f;
    [SerializeField] private Transform weaponSlideRotation;
    public bool isSliding = false;

I added the coditionals in my Update to start the Coroutine
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(slideKey) && characterController.isGrounded && !isSliding && isSprinting)
            {
                StartCoroutine(HandleSlide());
            }

And finally the actual Coroutine
private IEnumerator HandleSlide()
    {
        isSliding = true;
        float originalHeight = characterController.height;
        float originalSpeed = isCrouching ? crouchSpeed : isSprinting ? sprintSpeed : walkSpeed;
        Vector3 originalCenter = characterController.center;

        float targetHeight = crouchHeight;
        Vector3 targetCenter = crouchingCenter;

        Quaternion originalRotation = weaponSlideRotation.localRotation;
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(-4, 0, 0);

        float slideEndTime = Time.time + slideDuration;
        float transitionDuration = 0.2f; // Duration of the height and rotation transition
        float transitionStartTime = Time.time;

        // Interpolate height and center over transitionDuration
        while (Time.time - transitionStartTime < transitionDuration)
        {
            float t = Mathf.Clamp01((Time.time - transitionStartTime) / transitionDuration);
            characterController.height = Mathf.Lerp(originalHeight, targetHeight, t);
            characterController.center = Vector3.Lerp(originalCenter, targetCenter, t);

            // Handle weapon rotation transition
            float timeRotation = Mathf.Clamp01((Time.time - transitionStartTime) / transitionDuration);
            weaponSlideRotation.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(originalRotation, targetRotation, timeRotation);

            moveDirection = transform.forward * slideSpeed;
            characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
            yield return null;
        }

I'm sure this post has formatting errors but I just wanted to help :) Here's the final full Script
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControllerV2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool canMove { get; private set; } = true;
    public bool isSprinting => canSprint && Input.GetKey(sprintKey) && !isCrouching && Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0;
    private bool shouldJump => Input.GetKeyDown(jumpKey) && characterController.isGrounded;
    private bool shouldCrouch => Input.GetKeyDown(crouchKey) && !duringCrouchAnimation && characterController.isGrounded && !isSprinting ||
    Input.GetKeyUp(crouchKey) && !duringCrouchAnimation && characterController.isGrounded && !isSprinting;
    private bool shouldZoom => canZoom && characterController.isGrounded;

    [Header("Functional Options")]
    [SerializeField] private bool canSprint = true;
    [SerializeField] private bool canJump = true;
    [SerializeField] private bool canCrouch = true;
    [SerializeField] private bool canUseHeadbob = true;
    [SerializeField] private bool willSlideOnSlopes = true;
    [SerializeField] private bool canZoom = true;

    [Header("Controls")]
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode sprintKey = KeyCode.LeftShift;
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode jumpKey = KeyCode.Space;
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode crouchKey = KeyCode.C;
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode slideKey = KeyCode.LeftControl;
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode zoomKey = KeyCode.Mouse1;

    [Header("Movement Parameters")]
    [SerializeField] private float walkSpeed = 3.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float sprintSpeed = 6.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float crouchSpeed = 1.5f;
    [SerializeField] private float slopeSpeed = 8f;

    [Header("Look Parameters")]
    [SerializeField, Range(1, 10)] private float lookSpeedX = 2.0f;
    [SerializeField, Range(1, 10)] private float lookSpeedY = 2.0f;
    [SerializeField, Range(1, 100)] private float upperLookLimit = 80.0f;
    [SerializeField, Range(1, 100)] private float lowerLookLimit = 80.0f;

    [Header("Jumping Parameters")]
    [SerializeField] private float jumpForce = 8.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float gravity = 30.0f;

    [Header("Crouch Parameters")]
    [SerializeField] private float crouchHeight = 0.5f;
    [SerializeField] private float standingHeight = 2f;
    [SerializeField] private float timeToCrouch = 0.25f;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 crouchingCenter = new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0);
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 standingCenter = new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0);
    public bool isCrouching;
    private bool duringCrouchAnimation;

    [Header("Headbob Parameters")]
    [SerializeField] private float walkBobSpeed = 14f;
    [SerializeField] private float walkBobAmount = 0.05f;
    [SerializeField] private float sprintBobSpeed = 18f;
    [SerializeField] private float sprintBobAmount = 0.11f;
    [SerializeField] private float crouchBobSpeed = 8f;
    [SerializeField] private float crouchBobAmount = 0.025f;
    private float defaultYPos = 0;
    private float timer;

    [Header("Zoom Parameters")]
    [SerializeField] private float timeToZoom = 0.1f;
    [SerializeField] private float zoomFOV = 54f;
    private float defaultFOV;
    private Coroutine zoomRoutine;

    [Header("Sliding Parameters")]
    [SerializeField] private float slideSpeed = 8.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float slideDuration = 1.0f;
    [SerializeField] private Transform weaponSlideRotation;
    public bool isSliding = false;

    // Slope sliding parameters
    private Vector3 hitPointNormal;
    private bool isSlidingOnSlope
    { 
        get 
        {
            if(characterController.isGrounded && Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out RaycastHit slopeHit, 2f))
            {
                hitPointNormal = slopeHit.normal;
                return Vector3.Angle(hitPointNormal, Vector3.up) > characterController.slopeLimit;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    private Camera playerCamera;
    public CharacterController characterController;

    private Vector3 moveDirection;
    private Vector2 currentInput;

    private float rotationX = 0;

    private void Awake() 
    {
        playerCamera = GetComponentInChildren<Camera>();
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

        defaultYPos = playerCamera.transform.localPosition.y;

        defaultFOV = playerCamera.fieldOfView;

        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    private void Update() 
    {
        if (canMove)
        {
            HandleMovementInput();
            HandleMouseLook();

            if (canJump)
            {
                HandleJump();
            }

            if (canCrouch)
            {
                HandleCrouch();
            }

            if (canUseHeadbob)
            {
                HandleHeadbob();
            }

            if (shouldZoom)
            {
                HandleZoom();
            }

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(slideKey) && characterController.isGrounded && !isSliding && isSprinting)
            {
                StartCoroutine(HandleSlide());
            }

            ApplyFinalMovements();
        }
    }

    private void HandleMovementInput()
    {
        currentInput = new Vector2(
            (isCrouching ? crouchSpeed : isSprinting ? sprintSpeed : walkSpeed) * Input.GetAxis("Vertical"),
            (isCrouching ? crouchSpeed : isSprinting ? sprintSpeed : walkSpeed) * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")
        );

        float moveDirectionY = moveDirection.y;
        moveDirection = (transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * currentInput.x) + (transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right) * currentInput.y);
        moveDirection.y = moveDirectionY;
    }

    private void HandleMouseLook()
    {
        rotationX -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * lookSpeedY;
        rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(rotationX, -upperLookLimit, lowerLookLimit);

        playerCamera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationX, 0, 0);
        transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * lookSpeedX, 0);
    }

    private void HandleJump()
    {
        if (shouldJump)
        {
            moveDirection.y = jumpForce;
        }
    }

    private void HandleCrouch()
    {
        if (shouldCrouch)
        {
            StartCoroutine(CrouchStand());
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator CrouchStand()
    {
        if (isCrouching && Physics.Raycast(playerCamera.transform.position, Vector3.up, 1f))
        {
            yield break;
        }
        duringCrouchAnimation = true;

        float timeElapsed = 0;
        float targetHeight = isCrouching ? standingHeight : crouchHeight;
        float currentHeight = characterController.height;
        Vector3 targetCenter = isCrouching ? standingCenter : crouchingCenter;
        Vector3 currentCenter = characterController.center;

        isCrouching = !isCrouching;

        while (timeElapsed < timeToCrouch)
        {
            characterController.height = Mathf.Lerp(currentHeight, targetHeight, timeElapsed / timeToCrouch);
            characterController.center = Vector3.Lerp(currentCenter, targetCenter, timeElapsed / timeToCrouch);
            timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }

        characterController.height = targetHeight;
        characterController.center = targetCenter;

        duringCrouchAnimation = false;
    }

    private void HandleHeadbob()
    {
        if (!characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (Mathf.Abs(moveDirection.x) > 0.1f || Mathf.Abs(moveDirection.z) > 0.1f)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime * (isCrouching ? crouchBobSpeed : isSprinting ? sprintBobSpeed : walkBobSpeed);
            playerCamera.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(
                playerCamera.transform.localPosition.x,
                defaultYPos + Mathf.Sin(timer) * (isCrouching ? crouchBobAmount : isSprinting ? sprintBobAmount : walkBobAmount),
                playerCamera.transform.localPosition.z);
        }
    }

    private void HandleZoom()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(zoomKey))
        {
            if (zoomRoutine != null)
            {
                StopCoroutine(zoomRoutine);
                zoomRoutine = null;
            }

            zoomRoutine = StartCoroutine(ToggleZoom(true));
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(zoomKey))
        {
            if (zoomRoutine != null)
            {
                StopCoroutine(zoomRoutine);
                zoomRoutine = null;
            }

            zoomRoutine = StartCoroutine(ToggleZoom(false));
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator ToggleZoom(bool isEnter)
    {
        float targetFOV = isEnter ? zoomFOV : defaultFOV;
        float startingFOV = playerCamera.fieldOfView;
        float timeElapsed = 0;

        while (timeElapsed < timeToZoom)
        {
            playerCamera.fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(startingFOV, targetFOV, timeElapsed / timeToZoom);
            timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }

        playerCamera.fieldOfView = targetFOV;
    }

    private void ApplyFinalMovements()
    {
        if (!characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (willSlideOnSlopes && isSlidingOnSlope)
        {
            moveDirection += new Vector3(hitPointNormal.x, -hitPointNormal.y, hitPointNormal.z) * slopeSpeed;
        }

        characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private IEnumerator HandleSlide()
    {
        isSliding = true;
        float originalHeight = characterController.height;
        float originalSpeed = isCrouching ? crouchSpeed : isSprinting ? sprintSpeed : walkSpeed;
        Vector3 originalCenter = characterController.center;

        float targetHeight = crouchHeight;
        Vector3 targetCenter = crouchingCenter;

        Quaternion originalRotation = weaponSlideRotation.localRotation;
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(-4, 0, 0);

        float slideEndTime = Time.time + slideDuration;
        float transitionDuration = 0.2f; // Duration of the height and rotation transition
        float transitionStartTime = Time.time;

        // Interpolate height and center over transitionDuration
        while (Time.time - transitionStartTime < transitionDuration)
        {
            float t = Mathf.Clamp01((Time.time - transitionStartTime) / transitionDuration);
            characterController.height = Mathf.Lerp(originalHeight, targetHeight, t);
            characterController.center = Vector3.Lerp(originalCenter, targetCenter, t);

            // Handle weapon rotation transition
            float timeRotation = Mathf.Clamp01((Time.time - transitionStartTime) / transitionDuration);
            weaponSlideRotation.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(originalRotation, targetRotation, timeRotation);

            moveDirection = transform.forward * slideSpeed;
            characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
            yield return null;
        }

        // Ensure final values are set
        characterController.height = targetHeight;
        characterController.center = targetCenter;

        // Continue sliding until slideEndTime
        while (Time.time < slideEndTime)
        {
            moveDirection = transform.forward * slideSpeed;
            characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
            yield return null;
        }

        // Handle rotation back to original and reverse height/center transition
        transitionStartTime = Time.time;
        while (Time.time - transitionStartTime < transitionDuration)
        {
            float t = Mathf.Clamp01((Time.time - transitionStartTime) / transitionDuration);
            characterController.height = Mathf.Lerp(targetHeight, originalHeight, t);
            characterController.center = Vector3.Lerp(targetCenter, originalCenter, t);

            float timeRotation = Mathf.Clamp01((Time.time - transitionStartTime) / transitionDuration);
            weaponSlideRotation.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(targetRotation, originalRotation, timeRotation);
            yield return null;
        }

        // Ensure final values are set
        characterController.height = originalHeight;
        characterController.center = originalCenter;
        weaponSlideRotation.localRotation = originalRotation;
        
        isSliding = false;
    }
}


